# calloc() to a pointer in struct doesn't work on clang

Tags: c, malloc, clang, calloc

I have implemented a queue in C. Consider the below code:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct queue queue;
struct queue {
  int len;
  int head;
  int tail;
  int* array;
};

int main(int argc, char* argv[argc+1]) {
  int len = 12;
  queue* q = malloc(sizeof(q));
  *q = (queue){
    .array = calloc(len, sizeof(int)),
    .len = len,
  };
  for (int i = 0; i < len; i += 1) {
    printf("%d\n", q->array[i]);
  }
  free(q->array);
  free(q);
  return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

I used calloc() to initialize an array in the structure, but some values of the array are not zero.

```sh
$ clang -Wall -O0 -g -o queue.o queue.c && ./queue.o
952118112
32728
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
```

Why is that?

Comment: You need `sizeof *q`, not `sizeof q`. The first yields the size of an object, the second yields the size of a pointer. See https://ideone.com/L4CeuX

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This memory allocation

```
queue* q = malloc(sizeof(q));
```

is wrong. It allocates the memory only for a pointer not for an object of the type queue.

Write instead

```
queue* q = malloc(sizeof(*q));
```